# Drag doesn't work after mouseup in scope of drop container (Chrome, Edge)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, drag

When an element is dragged around and dropped somewhere in the page, the next element should have the same dragging behaviour as the first element.

I decided to implement the dragging with mouseevents instead of the drag and drop API. The dragged element should be rotatable during the dragging process with press on a button and this is not possible with the drag and drop API.

The problem happens if an element is dragged to the socpe of the drop container and the mouseup event happens in this scope. When the next element is dragged it isn't dragged as expected. There appears a grabbing cursor instead of a mouse cursor and the element doesn't follow the cursor. (In Chrome and Edge, in Firefox everything's fine)

Everything works as expected if an element is dragged over scope of the drop container and the mouseup event gets fired outside the scope.

[Here is a link to a gif where you can see the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpYfw.gif)

The problem happens in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox. There is a mouseevent feature not supported in Chrome/Edge but in Firefox: "Support for mouseEventInit optional region field". Enabling "Experimental Web Platform Features" in Chrome still didn't solve the problem.

Checking the events in Chrome developer tools and Firefox Developer Tools one difference is that the offsetX and offsetY is in Firefox "0" but in Chrome a value is assigned. Don't know if this points to the potential issue.

How can the right dragging behaviour can be also implemented for Chrome and Edge?

```js
const dragContainer = document.querySelector('#drag-container')
const dropContainer = document.querySelector('#drop-container')
const element1 = document.querySelector('#element-1')
const element2 = document.querySelector('#element-2')

makeElementDraggable(element1)
makeElementDraggable(element2)

function makeElementDraggable(element) {
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag)
  // Regards to: https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop
  function startDrag(ev) {
    element.style.position = 'absolute'
    element.style.zIndex = 1000

    document.body.append(element)

    moveAt(ev.pageX, ev.pageY)

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', reset)
  }

  function onMouseMove(ev) {
    moveAt(ev.pageX, ev.pageY)
  }

  function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
    element.style.left = pageX + 10 + 'px'
    element.style.top = pageY + 'px'
  }

  function reset() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    element.removeEventListener('mousedown', startDrag)
  }
}
```

```css
    #drag-container {
      width: 250px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #element-1 {
      background-color: aqua;
      width: 250px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    #element-2 {
      background-color: blueviolet;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    #drop-container {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="drag-container">
          <div id="element-1"></div>
          <div id="element-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="drop-container"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you have an replit or jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yes: https://replit.com/@dave88/Dragging-ships#script.js

Comment: I think something's missing in your example because the elements get removed when dragging on mouseup

Comment: I edited the code now, so that the elements aren't removed any more. Still it isn't the dropping behaviour as in my original code. I tried to reproduce the problem with the least code possible.